# Avoid public folder of laravel and open directly the root in web server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, webserver, laravel-4

I was going through all possible sample on internet to solve this. Still it is an headache.

I just want to avoid the 'public' in `www.mylaravelsite.com/public/` 
and make it like `www.mylaravelsite.com` for the root directory.

Now I do not want to avoid the security concern,So I learned `.htaccess` would be the best way.

Any solution friends ?

& advance thanks for interacting !

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybJYyU5FPv4     Watch this :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547891/how-to-run-laravel-in-root-directory-without-the-public-folder/65716511#65716511  use this link for better result.

Comment: Try **My Solution** It will work **everywhere**.  check Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222509/laravel-not-detecting-files-from-public-folder/69517681#69517681

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let's assume you have this folder structure in your server

```
.cpanel/
public_html/
public_ftp/
..
```

And the laravel folder structure is

```
app/
bootstrap/
public/
vendor/
composer.json
artisan
..
```

You can create a folder name mylaravelsite on your server inline with `public_html` and `public_ftp` folder, and copy to it the whole laravel application except the public folder because you will paste all of it contents on the `public_html`, so you have now:

```
.cpanel/
public_html/
public_html/packages
public_html/vendor
public_html/index.php
public_html/.htaccess
...
public_ftp/
mylaravelsite/
mylaravelsite/app
mylaravelsite/bootstrap
...
```

On your `public_html/index.php` change the following line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../mylaravelsite/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../mylaravelsite/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and also don't forget to change  `/mylaravelsite/bootstrap/paths.php` public path, you might use it.

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html',
```

Your site should be running.

Comment: Bro I have done everything as per your instructions, It is showing 404 page instead . what should I do ?

Comment: I've checked your site: http://www.dolovers.com/sagir, you already installed laravel successfully. I've also noticed you have route error. Specify your default root `(/)`. See the documentation: [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing)

Comment: thank you brother, I was having trouble with the php versions as web hosing was not supporting the 5.3 or greater versions directly. And brother that was a old address of my site, pls create an account on my new alpha testing of this app , http://dolovers.com/auth/signup. thanks for help :)

Comment: Is that the solution for laravel 4 or 4.2 because I couldn't find the /mylaravelsite/bootstrap/paths.php in my root directory and I'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Can you give solution for 5+ please , because I'm facing some difficulty with the latest version.

Comment: Not anymore @BakhtawarGIll Please see their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure). Laravel changes their directory structure.

Comment: For Laravel 5.2 just add this lines into `public/index.php` `$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});`

Answer (score 34):

Create .htaccess in root folder and write these line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For production server it is recommended that you point your domain directly to the public folder

Comment: My osx development environment required a leading slash in front of "public/$1"

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot, i search for this answer two days

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like the information you are missing is:

### Documentroot

This is also called the "web root". Apache specifically calls it the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) - Click that link for the official explanation.

Basically what it does is set which directory the server pulls files from. In Laravel, the document root should be the `public` folder.

Setting the DocumentRoot to `public` means that going to `http://mylaravelsite.com` in the browser will infact be "pointing" to the `public` folder as you want.

In the .htaccess file (actually, more likely in the [virtual host configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/)), you can set the `DocumentRoot` for your site:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/laravel-app/public
```

How you set this up depends on your hosting. Each hosting has different ways to setup a website and so we cannot answer that specifically for you - you should consult your web hostings tech support. The key point is that the `public` directory should be the web root, while everything else should be "behind the web root".

Fair warning tho: some hosting providers do not give you enough access to accomplish that.

Answer (score 7):

Just add .htaccess file on Laravel root if it's not present and add following lines in it, that's it,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: simplest solution. Thanks

Comment: Same suggestion which Anik gave.

Answer (score 7):

create .htacess file in the root directory of your laravel project and put this code in.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

OR add this code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Good. A little more change removes the index.php too.

Comment: Thanks man, this was the only .htaccess that make my project work!

Answer (score 5):

point your web directory to `public/`. If you are using apache this will work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www.mylaravelsite.com/public/
  ServerName www.mylaravelsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply bro. I want to upload it on web server, in this case what should I do ?

Comment: You have to change your apache config which you can't since you're hosting on a webhosting package instead of a virtual server or so.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, But Must not do it in real projects, it is just for starter to test Laravel and i have tested it with laravel 5.0 and it is ,cut index.php and .htaccess files from public folder and paste it in the root directory and change these two lines as

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

It is Highly Recommended not to use the above method without testing environment, and should use virtual host instead.

Comment: This worked for me. Just move the `.htaccess` and `index.php` files from the public directory into the root directory and change the bootstrap paths.

Comment: No, no and no. Don't do that. The reason why Laravel has the document root in a subdirectory is so that you don't have to expose your code to the public.

Comment: Please, `DO NOT CUT`. Simply `COPY`

Answer (score 1):

All you just need to change .env file in your laravel project files. if your laravel project inside in

Root/domain/public_html/laravel/

Go to .env file and edit

you need to edit app url path which should be

APP_URL=http://www.domainname.com/laravel/public/

Thats it your project will run now. if your laravel files is in public_html, then your app url must be like this

APP_URL=http://www.domainname.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### For Lumen

Let's think you have a folder path like: /var/www/project/microservice(lumen src)

/var/www => document root for localhost/

Target you want:
localhost/project/microservice[/foo...]  => localhost/project/microservice/public/foo...

I do this by .htaccess (placed at /project folder) like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(.*)$ %1public$1 [L,R=301,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

**On Server(Apache)**
Create *.htaccess* in the root folder and write below line

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Lean more on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/itxshakil/79dd360836e317828c096747e7a60a0d)

**On Local Development**
You can create a virtual host by adding the below line to your apache vhost config file.
Generally, you can find this file in *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf* file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/public/"
  ServerName www.mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```