# Laravel application displays only white page on live server

Tags: php, laravel

I have made an application using `Laravel 4.2` . It works well on Wamp, But when I uploaded it onto a shared host, it only displayed a blank page. I followed all the advice given in the following links but it still isn't working.

[Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server)

[Avoid public folder of laravel and open directly the root in web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923091/avoid-public-folder-of-laravel-and-open-directly-the-root-in-web-server)

I just realized that laravel 4.2 requires `php 5.4` or greater, but my host uses `php 5.3.28`. Can this be the cause of the problem? if not, then what is the reason I get only blank page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - using Laravel without the required version of PHP will absolutely give you problems. You'll have to either upgrade your webserver or ask your host if it is possible for them to upgrade or enable a newer version of PHP for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, when theres an error in PHP code there's only a blank page.

Try putting this in there

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions to storage folder. `chmod -R 0777 app/storage`

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *insecure.*** If you have done this on a production server, roll back and revert to sane permissions (for your use case, probably 755 or perhaps 775), and review whether this misconfiguration could have been used by an intruder to escalate privileges and/or facilitate lateral movement within your infrastructure. In the worst case, wipe the server and restore from known-good backups.

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
php  artisan key:generate
```

problem solved in my case

Comment: Can you an explanation?

Comment: I was having same issue then I recreated my application key by running the command which is mentioned above then everything is fine again