# Deploying a Laravel 5 project in subdirectory of public root

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to deploy a Laravel 5 app to a subdirectory of my web server root (public root being `/public_html` in this case as we're using Apache). The web server already has a non-Laravel site in the root public folder.

Most questions on this topic come down to using a subdomain instead of a subdirectory, however as we're using an organisational SSL cert without subdomain coverage we cannot do this.

I realise we could still plop the non-public resources above `public_html`, the public resources in a subdirectory and then hack at the paths required, but I haven't found any concrete instructions for how to achieve this. Is there a standard approach for this use case?

Comment: It's for laravel 4, but this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923091/avoid-public-folder-of-laravel-and-open-directly-the-root-in-web-server

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sub-folder as `public_html/new_project` (or whatever name you give as per your coding conventions). And create another folder on the same level as the `public_html` for non-public resources as eg: `new_project_resources`.

1. Now copy all everything except the `public` folder from your `laravel project` and upload it to the `new_project_resources folder (on server)`.
2. Open the `public` folder of your `laravel project` and copy everything and upload it to the `public_html/new_project` folder (on server).
3. Now open `index.php` file from `public_html/new_project` and

   ```
   Change:  
   require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';  
   To:  
   require __DIR__.'/../../new_project_resources/bootstrap/autoload.php';  
   And  
   Change:  
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';  
   To:  
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../new_project_resources/bootstrap/app.php';  
   Save and Close.
   ```
4. Now go to `new_project_resources` folder and open `server.php` file

   ```
   Change:  
   require_once __DIR__.'../public/index.php';  
   To:  
   require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/new_project/index.php';  
   Save and close.
   ```

   Things should work now from the subfolder. 
   Hop it helps.