# Can't write image data to path laravel 5.2

Tags: php, image, laravel-5

I host my laravel application in a seared hosting and i upload my laravel project into the root directory and i upload my public folder into the public_html directory .

Image 
[image]

i want to save image in `avater_img` or `assistant_img` or `doctor_img`.

**For thereby i write this code**

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
        if($file != ""){
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file_name = rand(10000,50000).'.'. $ext;
            $image = Image::make(Input::file('photo'));
            $image->resize(300,300);
            $image->save(public_path() . '/doctor_img/' . $file_name);
        }
```

And it give this error back
[image]

How can i fix this error

Comment: What did Google have to say about this error? Did you attempt any fixes that Google suggested? If so, what happened then?

Comment: Try taking a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19923994/2079781 although you might have to change some things to work on Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using the default Laravel file structure, therefore your public_path() is still pointed into /home/dermopres/laravel/public as mentioned in the error message.

First thing that you should do is set your Laravel application according to your current file structure.

On your public_html/index.php change the following line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and also add this line to the /laravel/bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__.'/../../public_html';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the doctor_img directory writable

if you are on linux / homestead

run below on terminal

```
sudo chmod 666 -R /home/dermopres/laravel/public/doctor_img
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image path is wrong.
It should be like this.

> $image->save(public_path() . '../doctor_img/' . $file_name);

As public_path() goes to public folder.