# Laravel 5.2 Avoiding public folder and open directly from root in localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5

The reason why I'm doing that is  `Laravel has the document root in a subdirectory is so that you don't have to expose your code to the public.`

The folder structure in my localhost is

```
Test
    Test/laravel/
    Test/public_html/
```

where laravel contains all the folder of root without the public folder and public_html contains the public files.

And I have changed in below lines in `public_html/index.php`:

```
require __DIR__.'./../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'./../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I have followed the  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923091/avoid-public-folder-of-laravel-and-open-directly-the-root-in-web-server) for solving the problem but couldn't solve it as I'm using 5.2. If anyone has done this before please provide a valid solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already comes with the public directory (which would be easily renamed public_html).  However, looking at your code, an issue lies at `**./**../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'`

This would end up with a directory like `Test./` instead of `Test/`.  Remove the period before the first slash.

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: But I'm getting Url like localhost/test/laraver/xxxx , But laravel shouldn't be add with the url like url should be like localhost/test/xxx .. So How do i remove the laravel from the url?