# Laravel 5: How to avoid public folder, trying to open from root in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following the following Structure as I don't want to expose my code to the public.

The folder structure in my localhost is

```
tbt
    tbt/user/
    tbt/public_html/
```

where user contains all the folder of root without the public folder and public_html contains the public files.

And I have changed in below lines in public_html/index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../user/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../user/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But when i run the application,

I'm getting Url like `localhost/tbt/user/xxxx`   But it should be `localhost/tbt/xxx`

I have followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958149/laravel-5-2-avoiding-public-folder-and-open-directly-from-root-in-localhost/37958193#37958193) for solving the problem but couldn't solve it as My application is on Laravel 5. Anyone who can help me to find the solution please?

Comment: Try this :
`require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: `Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\index.php on line 27`

Line 27 :` require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

Comment: look like your root forget `tbl`, try to add `/..` before `/bootstrap`

Comment: Same Error I'm getting >> `Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\index.php on line 27`

Answer (score 1):

**Process 1**

1. Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php
2. copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder.

**Process 2**

3. Follow process 1
4. Update the .htaccess as below

.htaccess look like below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: My problem isn't about removing public from url actually I want to host my application from 'public_html' and facing difficulty with that!

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a alias in your web server, pointing to your public folder. It's simple but works for me

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Answer (score 1):

In the root directory of your Laravel project create a file with name `.htacess` and paste this code in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```