# how to protect directories being visit by user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am trying to hide directories from being visit by user on my website
here is the link I have which is fine

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/storage/app/public/newpaper_jobs/230_Govrenment-Of-The-Punjab-Agriculture-Department.jpg
```

But when I type

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/storage/app/public/newpaper_jobs
```

I got the list of my images which I don't want to show
I place an empty `index.php` file but it work for particular directory not for sub directories.

What is the best possible way to secure my directories?

Comment: Remove from htdocs folder and reroute using php

Comment: can i have an example to get your idea what if when i live my site that again directories will work when publish website in public_html folder @RobertRocha

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923091/avoid-public-folder-of-laravel-and-open-directly-the-root-in-web-server

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep those assets in a folder that is not public.  A few approaches can be found in this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-secure-assets-images-and-docs)